Make changes to the viewBox in AS3SVGRenderer lucaslorentz library for zooming and paning
I am using the AS3SVGRenderer library to draw SVG shapes with ActionScript. I have no trouble drawing shapes, but I cannot access the 'viewBox' to use it for zooming
Can someone help?
The code I wrote:
`package 
{
    import com.lorentz.SVG.display.SVG;
    import com.lorentz.processing.ProcessExecutor;
    import com.lorentz.SVG.display.SVGDocument;
    import com.lorentz.SVG.display.SVGRect;
    import com.lorentz.SVG.events.SVGEvent;
    import com.lorentz.SVG.data.style.StyleDeclaration;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    
    public class svgDrawer extends Sprite
    {
        private var svgDoc:SVGDocument;
        private var rect:SVGRect;
        private var svg:SVG;
        
        public function svgDrawer()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            
            svgDoc = new SVGDocument();
        }
        
        private function init(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, zoom);
            
            ProcessExecutor.instance.initialize(stage);
            
            addChild(svgDoc);
            
            svg = new SVG();
            svg.svgViewBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, 600, 400);
            svgDoc.addElement(svg);
            
            rect = new SVGRect();
            rect.svgX = '30';
            rect.svgY = '30';
            rect.svgWidth = '60';
            rect.svgHeight = '40';
            svgDoc.addElement(rect);
            //So far, there is no issue, and a black rectangle is being drawn
        }
        
        private function zoom(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            //With this code, the ViewBox should change and zoom, but no changes are observed
            svg.svgViewBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 200);
            
            //I added this code as well, but still no changes occurred
            svgDoc.validate();
        }
    }
}`

Are there examples of how to use this library? I would appreciate it if someone could provide guidance.
